# C++ Callbacks -- std::function vs Function Pointer

Tags: c++, c++11

Having an interesting problem and looking for some clarification.  I have working example using old function pointer method, but was attempting to use a std::function wrapper, but now it no longer works.

The example code was to start implementing a callback mechanism, when I use the function pointer approach I obtain the desired results.

```
callback initiated, m_callback = 0
callback initiated, m_callback = 1
callback initiated, m_callback = 0
callback initiated, m_callback = 1
...
```

But when using the std::function wrapper approach I do not get the intended results.

```
callback initiated, m_callback = 0
callback initiated, m_callback = 0
callback initiated, m_callback = 0
callback initiated, m_callback = 0
...
```

Anyone able to point out any errors that I've made?  I comment/uncomment between the two approaches (function pointers vs function wrapper).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

void callback(int callback)
{
    int m_callback = callback;
    std::cout << "m_callback = " << m_callback << std::endl;
}

void foo(void (*ptr)(int))
// void foo(std::function<void(int)> ptr)
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
    int callback = (callback == 0) ? 1 : 0;
    ptr(callback);
}

// ----------------------------------------------------------------

int main(int argc, char ** agrv)
{
    void (*func_ptr)(int) = &callback;
    std::function<void(int)> std_func_ptr = &callback;

    while(1)
    {
        foo(func_ptr);
        // foo(std_func_ptr);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Undefined behavior. You're reading from an uninitialized variable (`callback`).

Comment: did you mean to use `static int callback`?

Comment: yes...that worked

Comment: Thanks both, stupid error on my part

Comment: fyi, if you want a stateful callback, you should not use static local variables to achieve this. The issue is that you can never "reset" that state, a static local is basically a global in that sense. static locals have a few isolated uses, but generally once you start having a state you should use a function object/lambda.